# Error while using pointers and new operators in C++(Microsoft VS)

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio, pointers, new-operator

i was using pointers and new operator for printing different city names. But the Microsoft Visual Studio show that it is **Exception thrown:read access violation**.
This happen even when i write `*ptr=n;` or `*ptr=20;` ,but works properly if i give `ptr=&n;` (if n is the variable with some value).

Program to display names of cities

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
class city
{
protected:
    char *name;
    int len;
public:
    char *s;
    city();
    ~city();
    void getdata()
    {

        s = new char[20];
        cout << "enter the name of city" << endl;
        cin >> s;
        len = strlen(s);
        name = new char[len + 1];
        strcpy_s(name, 10, s);



    }

    void display()
    {
        cout << *name << endl;
    }

private:


};

city::city()
{
    len = 0;//initialization
    name = NULL;

}

city::~city()
{

    delete[]name;
    delete[]s;

}
int main() 
{
    city *obj[10];
    int n = 0;
    int en=0;
    do 
    {
        obj[n] = new city;
        obj[n]->getdata();
        n++;
        obj[n]->display();
        cout << "do you want to enter another city?" << endl;
        cout << "(enter 1 for yes and 0 for no"<<endl;
        cin >> en;

    } while (en);
    delete[]obj;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FKdC.png)

Comment: use the debugger. hint: around `n++`

Comment: `obj` is an automatic array. You are not allowed to `delete` it.

Comment: `int main() { city c; }` -- That simple program invokes undefined behavior due to not initializing the `s` member.  Why not simply use `std::string`?

Answer (score 0):

Don't manage memory manually! Use STL to forget memory manage!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
class city
{
protected:
    std::string name;
public:
    city() = default;
    //~city();
    void getdata()
    {
        std::cout << "enter the name of city" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> this->name;
    }

    void display()
    {
        std::cout << name << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    std::array<city, 10> obj;
    for(auto&& o : obj)
    {
        o.getdata();
        o.display();
        std::cout
            << "do you want to enter another city?" << std::endl
            << "(enter 1 for yes and 0 for no" << std::endl;
        int en=0;
        std::cin >> en;
        if(0 == en) return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/bz4iF3LNDSyUIZPb